# Finding routs from A to B

Tags: python

I would like to get help in my Python code: I have a 2D List which represents all to places I can get from certain point

```
[[], [2], [3, 4, 5], [4], [5, 6], [6], []]
```

From point 1 i can get to point 2

From point 2 I can get to points 3 4 and 5

etc... (from point 0 I can't get to anywhere and point 0 just not exist so I keep it blank)

I am trying find all the possible roots I can get from some point to another point.

I tried to do something for specific to get from point 2 to 5 and and then generalize it.

So I need the following paths:

```
2345 
245
25
```

This is the code I have written:

```
def finding_route(comp_list, origin, dest, st="2", possible_routes=[]):
for flights in comp_list[origin]:
    st += str(flights)
    if flights == dest:
        possible_routes.append(st)
    return finding_route(comp_list, flights, dest, st, possible_routes)
return possible_routes
```

And I get only 2345

From what I understand I don't get the other results, because I don't "go back" to the beginning of the recursion and just continue, while I want to go back after I am done with "3"

I need to find the paths from "4", but I am stuck on how I could go back to there

Another problem I have is that I am limited with what I can use basically I can only use function loops list tuple and dictionary

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me correct this code.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The return statement inside your loop prevents the remaining paths from being considered.  You can fix that by adding to your result list instead of returning or by using yield which will turn your function into an iterator.  When you get to that point, you'll have the additional concern of not falling into infinite loops through the nodes (that don't reach the destination).  That can be managed by carrying a list of visited nodes through the recursion so you can stop digging when you're back to a starting point.

Here's an example:

```
links = [[], [2], [3, 4, 5], [4], [5, 6], [6], []]

def findPaths(links,origin,destination,seen=set()):
    if origin == destination: yield (origin,);return
    if origin in seen: return
    for nextNode in links[origin]:
        for path in findPaths(links,nextNode,destination,seen|{origin}):
            yield (origin,)+path

list(findPaths(links,2,5))
[(2, 3, 4, 5), (2, 4, 5), (2, 5)]
```

without yield:

```
def findPaths(links,origin,destination,seen=set()):
    if origin == destination: return [(origin,)]
    if origin in seen: return
    result = []
    for nextNode in links[origin]:
        for path in findPaths(links,nextNode,destination,seen|{origin}):
            result.append((origin,)+path)
    return result
```

Comment: well I can't use yield
I can assume that there will not be cycles 
can you try to help me in fixing my recursion?